# Content loaded by jQuery load() adapts CSS styling of parent page

Tags: jquery

I have tried for a while and i don't know if it's my search skills, if no one has asked the question before or if it's even possible.

Currently i am loading a file using `.load('path/to/file.php');` but the file i am loading inherits all the styling from the site its loaded to.

Is it possible to load the file without adapting the styling from the site it's being loaded into?

There are no options in the `.load()` api that mentions this problem, and i do imagine that in most cases it's not an issue. My options are to re-declare every style element for the included file, which is a major task and seems quite unnecessary for this situation.

Comment: Well thats a normal behavior. Load is used to `load` partial content instead of refreshing the whole page. The content you load should not be seen as something independent but as a part of the page you load to (with its styling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may have an easy solution.  Load the content into an `iframe` which I think will isolate it from the rest of the page with respect to CSS styling.

Read the following: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Most people have the opposite problem, they want to apply the parent styling to the content within the `iframe`, and you want to do the inverse.

In this case, you may not need to even use AJAX or jQuery `load()`, just link to your file using the `src` attribute in the `iframe`.

**Comment**

What you have here is a case of **embedded content**, which is discussed in the HTML5 specification under the `iframe` tag section.  Using the `ifrmae` tag in this application is very appropriate.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element

Comment: Thank you. iframe solved my issue, while it's a dirty solution then it works surprisingly well in the situation i need it.

Comment: NO!!! not dirty, elegant! This is what you needed for this problem. Have faith in the spec!

Answer (score 1):

CSS will always be applied to the whole page (according to selectors of course). The only way to do what you ask is by using an iframe in which you will be loading the ajax page this way it will be independent.

Another way that COULD work is by resetting the whole CSS definitions in the container but that is error prone.